# Custom output file name in Hive 0.11

Tags: amazon-s3, hive

My Hive job produces output file name prefixing block number/name-0000 in AWS S3. I would like to have the file name as part-00000. Can someone please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this –

1. Using a Java class that derives from MultipleOutputFormat as the jobs output format allows control of the output file names.
   // job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
   LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
   MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, “text”, TextOutputFormat.class,Text.class, IntWritable.class);
2. Using (this I have tested and working)
   job.getConfiguration().set(“mapreduce.output.basename”, “text”);
   part name will change and file will be created as text-r-00000